# PHP MYSQLdisplaying unwanted span tags

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am submitting some text to a MYSQL database using php, however I am getting some unwanted styling with the text. I am wanting to basically keep all the text in one paragraph tag and just have breaks to separate the lines. When I look at the text in the database it is included with all the styling tags such as brs', spans' and divs'. I want the break tags but not the spans and divs. Why would this be happening and how can I prevent the spans and divs from being included with the inserted text. I will provide my code below.

here is the php update code

```
if($_POST['about']){

  $edit_desciption = $_POST['about'];
  $id = 1;

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE table_name SET about = ? WHERE id = ?');
  $stmt->bind_param("si", $edit_desciption, $id); 

  $stmt->execute();

  // echo $final_outputs;

  $stmt->close();
  $conn->close();
  header("Location: ../../admin_login/logged_in.php");


 //$connect->close();
}
```

and here is the form

```
    function getContent(){
       document.getElementById("about").value = document.getElementById("about_edit").innerHTML;
    }

   <p id="about_edit" contentEditable="true"><?php echo $output; ?></p>
   <div class="col-12">
     <form id="update_CMS" onsubmit="return getContent()" action="../includes/php/edit.php" Method="POST">
        <textarea id="about" name="about" style="display: none;"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="edit_submit" />
     </form>
   </div>
```

Comment: you should use `htmlspecialchars`. if you do not want any html or php character then you can try `strip_tags` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: the only issues is when I use those, I cant keep the breaks

Comment: actually, strip_tags allows you to specify a list of tags to keep. So you can strip out everything that is not a br or p tag.

Comment: in this condition I suggest you to create `regex` for your own tags.

Comment: Awesome thanks so much!, I got it. I tried doing that eairler and was getting issues but its working now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
 strip_tags($_POST['about'], '<br><p>')
```

works